# WooCommerce Plugin or script - Bulk orders enquiries

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email, woocommerce

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a section of my site that retailers can log into to make bulk orders. It wouldn't need to have pricing (because I might have negotiated different prices with different retailers). What it would need is simply a place where they can make an order on a checklist of products, and then submit it via email...

Does anyone know a plugin that does this?  (doesn't matter if you don't have to login)

Is there some easy way that i can GET all the products names and number in my WooCommerce store and add them to a email form will the product number and a box to add qty... like this:

PHP wise? Any help would be great!

[image]

Comment: this question belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a page template, and build your form like so:

```
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => '',
            'offset'           => 0,
            'category'         => '',
            'orderby'          => 'post_date',
            'order'            => 'DESC',
            'include'          => '',
            'exclude'          => '',
            'meta_key'         => '',
            'meta_value'       => '',
            'post_type'        => 'product',
            'post_mime_type'   => '',
            'post_parent'      => '',
            'post_status'      => 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => true );

        $products = get_posts( $args );

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            //echo out your table, eg
            $pid = $product->ID;
            $pname = $product->post_title;
            $inputName = $pid.'quantity';

            echo "<tr>
                    <td>$pid</td>
                    <td>$pname</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='$inputName' value=''> </td>
                  </tr>";
        }
```